# Add a custom input text field in admin order create

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I displayed a custom text filed under order comments. But i am unable to save that value using observer. I tried lot but couldn't able get that text value. I checked the network call there it sends the value to the controller. Pls help

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: yes @jibingeorge check the answer.